# Display array data in table using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to display some array of data in table using Rails 3. suppose I have the below array of data.

```
@vendor_type=["SWD", "GOODS","SWD"]
```

My database structure is given below.

```
table- Payment_vendors:
id  Receipt_No   type   v_amount    v_date      c_date      v_name    v_status

7    150325005   SWD     60.00     2015-04-15  2015-04-28   Deepak    No

8    150325006   GOODS   1195.00   2015-04-15  2015-04-28   Deepak    No
9    150325007   SWD      60.00    2015-04-15  2015-04-29   Deepak    No
```

Actually My requirement is when `@vendor_type==SWD`,it will retrieve all Receipt_no corresponding to that "SWD".According to the Receipt_No corresponding row data will fetch and append in the below table.

> paymentdetails.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></th>
            <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
            <th class="text-center">Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Receipt No.</th>
            <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1-1" name="checkbox1-1"></th>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller file is given below.

> payments_controller.rb:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

    def payment
        @payment=Vendor.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.js
        end

    end
    def check_type  
        if params[:commit]=="submit"
           @vendor_type=PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).pluck(:type )
           #@vendor_type=PaymentVendor.pluck_all(PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]),:type ,:Receipt_No)

        else
            @v_name=Vendor.where(:s_catagory => params[:payment][:s_catagory] ).pluck(:v_name)
        end
    end
end
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for here. Are you asking someone what should go in the `paymentdetails.html.erb`? You don't have any actual ERB writing in your .erb file. Also, are you trying to display the data in your `@vendor_type` array? It sounds like you want to display a bunch of data related to that array, but not the actual data in the `@vendor_type` array.

Comment: "when @vendor_type==SWD,it will retrieve all Receipt_no corresponding to that "SWD" appears impossible since you have two "SWD" in your array and your array has no way to indicate WHICH row it came from. You are using `.pluck(:type)` to get this array, losing any connection between the items and the array and their data that they came from. You should only use `.pluck` if you really just want certain columns. I would not use `.pluck`, as you can just use column methods in the ERB file to display what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give a best guess at what you want but I think what you are trying to ask for is this:

1) Change this line in `check_type` method in PaymentsController:

```
@vendor_type=PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name])
```

this gets rid of the .pluck method and returns an array of PaymentVendor objects instead of just the column :type.

Now in your ERB file you need a looping structure that will create rows in the table body for each item in the @vendor_type data structure:

```
...
</thead>
  <tbody>
   <% @vendor_type.each do |vt| %>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1-1" name="checkbox1-1"></th>
        <td class="text-center">????? what column does "Sl. No" refer to??? </td> 
        <td class="text-center"><%= vt.v_date %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= vt.receipt_no %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"><%= vt.v_amount %></i></td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't clarify anything for me. What is Sl short for??? Please do not use abbreviations and assume others can understand them. And more importantly, since you've had a chance to look at this answer, does it even come close? Is this the question you are asking?

Comment: Well does any of my answer help or make sense?